# What's the most efficient way to make money?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

What's the most efficient way to make money?  Is there a good place to farm with a relatively high $$$ drop, or even one-time loots that are especially well rewarding?

Comment: I don't know about the one-time loots. I think a lot of chest items are entirely random.

Comment: Not as good as the [Nethack] question titles, but good enough for a +1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What is working for me is a combination of the following:

- Smash everything

All the chests and destructible items add up ... a box killing rampage earns a slow but steady income.  If you use a chakram or some area affecting magic, it's not even that slow.  Don't miss the sunken treasure, look for ripples on the water to indicate their presence.

- Change your shards to gems

A shard sells for around 150, a gem for around 1000.  It's pretty basic math to see that combining 2 shards before selling them more than triples your income from them.  Suddenly Sagecraft + Mercantilism start paying off.

- Detect hidden your way to fame and fortune, well fortune anyway

Don't pass up the chance to hit a small hidden area with even more treasure.  Hidden treasure, doors and such will add enough to a regular walk through of an area to make it well worth it.

- Loot everything in sight

This game isn't cheap on the pops, and it's your personal mission to supply the Kingdoms of Amalur shopkeepers with every kind of crap imaginable.

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way I've found to make money is quests.  There are so many quests in this game - it's impossible to throw a chakram without hitting a questgiver in most of the towns.

In addition to the (usually small) cash bonus for finishing a quest, quests will take you around the map and pit you against a variety of enemies, both of which are certain to help you turn up loot.  Most of the loot in this game is shop fodder.

I'd also suggest taking a couple of ranks in the "Detect Hidden" skill as early as possible - this skill will show you caches of hidden items that practically litter each area.  Each one tends to have at least one or two magical items that you can pilfer at your leisure.  Additionally, having ranks of Detect Hidden sometimes causes you to get bonus gold from chests and destructible items, which is also useful.

Comment: It'll also occasionally increase the gold you get from enemies!

Answer (score 2):

Combination of a lot of different ideas like selling the gems, bumping sagecraft, detect hidden and mercantile skills being a few along with participating in as many side quests as possible all I would echo as recommendations.

But one that I haven't seen anywhere is Rose Barden and dice roll Gamble at the Star Camp in the Sidhe.

She will bump into if you hang around the camp long enough unless she's asleep on a blanket somewhere in the camp. When she offers you a roll of the dice, save then take the bet.

Obviously if you win save your game and repeat, and if you lose exit and re-load from the save point.

Save after each win and if you are patient enough 10-12 rolls you can make about 4,000.00.

Yes it takes time but it is a sure win as long you remember not to save when you lose and only save the positive results :).

There are other trainers in the area as well as a buy sell merchart and that 4,000 bucks could pay off for training in stealth and mercantile I believe or getting health potions and recipes which you always need to survive and progress in the game.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you escape the well of souls, you can run (like crazy) to the moon camp.  I got there at level 2.  There is a lady named MINN THE GRINNER, who loves to roll dice.  Ok, ask her to play high roll and if you win let her say what she says, ("A loss...") and collect your money. Do not stop her from saying what she says if you win, or you will not get your money! However if you loose ask her again to play before she tells you, you lost.  doing this keeps her from winning.  You can keep playing without stopping, as long as you never let her respond to your loss. You can get about 10,000 gold every 3-4 minutes if you get fast.  GL, Hf.   Oh, one important thing, you need at least 1,236 gold to play with her.  That should not be much of a problem at all.  Also when you get to Galafor go around the bottom to get to the Moon camp because there are some BAD NASTY dudes if you go above Galafor. Sorry, one other thing, ask to see the dice and let her respond.  Minn the Grinner loves to cheat!

Oh, one important thing, you need at least 1,236 gold to play with her. That should not be much of a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Sell everything you don't need in the beginning except if you get good items and your blacksmthing is up enough then make items to sell.  Find the following tasks and you will be paid over and over for completing the tasks:  Dangerous games, Sartorial Splendor, Tinker's Task, Dinner Time, Rogue Harvest, Gathering Flames.  Complete as many side quests as you can as you will be paid and you will find many things to sell.  Later in the game items you find will sell for more.  When I ended the game I had over $3,000,000, and had made all of my own armour (mastercrafted) and weapons which were better than any I found or could buy in the game.  My sagecrafting was also up so I was making epic gems for my armour.

Answer (score 1):

When I was a low level, I tried to do a Warsworn quest, took about 10 minutes ish. Get this weird yellow item (part of set,) hell I thought, might as well sell it. Turns out it was like 20k. When your a low level **that's a lot**.

You don't usually need money for anything but training, and gambling :D

Dont spend money on shitty store items if you do, the next time you go to a dungeon you'll probably get a better item. Buy very expensive shit equaling 200k on xbox for achievement.

SMASH EVERYTHING ( 15G ACHIEVEMENT (XBOX) FOR 1K CRATE SMASH ) I got like a few thousand gold for a shitty long ass achievement and/or for money.

SHARD CRAFITNG, ( LEVEL 16, NOT 8 ) In gorhat find the apothecary, do the quest, come back when done, ( AWESOME BONUS FOR SELLING AND BUYING IN THE APOTHECARY ) get crappy non epic gems, make em epic, and sell. for 30% ( GUESS ) extra cash

LOOT, SELL, LOOT, SELL,

STEAL, JOIN TRAVELERS, SELL.